# css divs display:none reseting and showing divs when function is called

Tags: jquery, css, function, checkbox

Hi guys i'm new to this site so don't be too harsh on me :P
basically I have created a function where onclick certain divs(ones with the word "false" in
them) are selected and the css display:none function is called. As can hopefully be seen here:

```
...
if (tickbox.checked == false) {
    var unchecked = $("div:contains('true'):not(div:contains('false')").css("display", "none");    
}
...
```

this is linked to a checkbox which calls the function everytime a checkbox is clicked (It serves to hide information that has been displayed when the checkbox was checked, when it is unchecked(sorry hard to understand). The problem is that whenever I check another checkbox it seems to reset this function causing all unchecked checkboxes to display their information which should be hidden.

If anyone can tell me how to sort out this problem or even write a new function that completely gets rid of the information div instead of just hiding it, as I feel this would sort the problem, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do the other check boxes do? Do they have their own onclick functions, if so, what are they?

Comment: could you show us some more code? Perhaps set up a fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If you can, use http://jsfiddle.net/ and put your code in there, save it and post a link here. This will help us understand what you are doing and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eK6gw/) of what I've written which would show and hide the divs with he text "false" in them, based on the checkbox value.

Comment: Quick question regarding your answer, is there a way to set the function to all checkboxes in the document, so not referring to ids but tickboxes as a whole?

Comment: You just need to do `$('input[type=checkbox]').change(...)`. Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eK6gw/3/)